# Wordpress - issues uploading to live URL

Tags: wordpress

hoping someone can help.

I'm uploading a wordpress site to it's soon to be live URL - I've created a holding page 'template' so that I can test behind the scenes without anyone getting to the site.

However, although everything is uploaded, I'm having issues navigating between URLS. I can see the holding page just fine - and any other static page that i set as the 'home page' but as soon as i try to navigate or indeed type the URL directly into the browser bar, I'm getting the default 'domain parked' page.

I've tried several time snow and have no idea what could be wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Vikki

Comment: Make sure you followed the steps [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server) when moving site.

Comment: Hi, yes database was exported, config changed, new database on live URL created etc. It just doesn't seem to want to play. As i said, wordpress is installed correctly on the new server and the theme directory is working fine, it's just a problem with the navigation. The server (or database even) even doesn't seem to think the paths/directory exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You may need to refresh permalinks.**

1. Navigate to http://`yourlivesite`/wp-admin/options-permalink.php
2. Click SAVE CHANGES
3. It should alert 'permalink structure updated'. If not make a frivolous change to get it to do so, e.g. change permalink structure and then revert